# Pointer class definition

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

Can someone explain what it is when a pointer is used as the name of the class when adding a method to the class? Something like this:

```
cMessage *Tic9::generateNewMessage()
```

Can't find a way to search for that on google and my C++ knowledge is lacking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't used as the name of the class, it's part of the return type, pure and simple.

That declares a member (of `Tic9`) function named `generateNewMessage` which takes no parameters and returns a `cMessage*` (a pointer).  Since it can't be the in-class declaration (which wouldn't be qualified by the class name), presumably it's part of an out-of-class definition of the function (a definition is a declaration).

Or, if a declaration isn't legal in the current context, it's an expression multiplying `cMessage` by the result of calling a static member (of `Tic9`) function named `generateNewMessage`.

Comment: Writing it as `cMessage* Tic9::generateNewMessage()` makes it more clear.

Comment: @DrCoder If this answers your question, you should accept the answer.

Comment: @KerrekSB  Don't be such a goody-goody -- living dangerous is fun!

Comment: @Kerrek: Using pointers is only "evil" if you have the "luxury" of consuming API's that other people have written and don't work mired in low level detail.  Everyone should know how to use them.